# Correct pattern for declaring REST service api endpoints in client application?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, swift

This is a code style and architectural question. And it is not specific only for iOS or Android. What is the best and the most correct way for declaring\storing REST api's endpoints(urls) in the client app? Let's say I have a client app for some social network or whatever rest service. This service has a lot of different api endpoints: `user/login`, `user/profile`, `common/list` and so on and so forth. There can be a large number of this endpoints. So the question how should I correctly manage this in my client's app? Right now I just declare string constants like this for iOS: `static NSString * const kLoginUser = @"user/login"`, Swift: `let loginUser = "user/login"` or in Android: `"private final String LOGIN_USER = "user/login"`.

But if the web-service is rather complex there can be 40-50 such string constants or more. And I wondered: maybe I do it in a wrong way, and there are more elegant ways for managing endpoints in REST clients? Any explanations or interesting approaches will be very helpful.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: @RomanC I said this in my question: `Right now I just declare string constants like this`

Comment: This question is quite broad and has many different solutions. Also, why do you invert your constant names? Wouldn't it be clearer to name a constant `kUserLogin = @"user/login"`?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Thanks for the advice. Seems reasonable. Can you please told how do you manage endpoints? Also declare constants?

Comment: How many places are you using a given endpoint value? Personally, if I am using the endpoint value in exactly one place, I don't even bother with declaring a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a better way as to hold the endpoint URLs (or unique parts of them) in some constants. If you read them from some configuration files, this is still a constant, that should not change in the runtime.

If you are overwhelmed by a large number of enpoints - group them. Respect the "S" of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) - group the related enpoints in one Class. E.g. put the methods accessing *user/login*, *user/profile*, *user/something_else* in a `UserServices` class, *common/a*, *common/b*, *common/the_rest* in `CommonServices`. The String constants with the enpoint URLs will be defined in this Services classes.

Answer (score 1):

The way I generally see it done is to create an enum for your various service calls:

```
protected enum SpecificRestServiceMethods implements RestServiceMethods{
   EXAMPLE_REST_CALL_ONE("/example/service/examplerestcallone"),
   EXAMPLE_REST_CALL_TWO("/example/service/examplerestcalltwo"),
   //etc etc

   private String path;
   private SpecificRestServiceMethods(String path){
     this.path = path;
   }

   public String getName(){
     return this.name();
   }
   public String getPath(){
     return path;
   }
}
```

Then just plop that chunk in whatever class is handling your general REST stuff.

Comment: can enums in java handle parameters?  What about:

EXAMPLE_CALL_THREE("/example/service/{0}");

Comment: I don't see why not. All you're really doing with that particular enum is storing a String path with a placeholder for your parameter. Once you fetch the path from EXAMPLE_CALL_THREE if you're using something like Spring framework's RestTemplate then parameters will insert nicely. Otherwise you could always use the String code %s instead of {0} and then String.format to insert parameters after the path is fetched.